# How To Style Qt's Tab Bar Background on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, qtstylesheets, qtabwidget, qtabbar

With Qt on OSX, is there a way to change the dark tab bar background color inside the QTabWidget?

I've tried all kinds of QSS stylesheet stuff and can change everything but that.

Maybe I can do it by intercepting and the palette? Maybe I can intercept the paint events? Maybe I can set some transparency?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an undocumented solution off of [Github](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/blob/master/qdarkstyle/style.qss) from Colin Duquesnoy that showed me the technique:

```
QTabBar {
background-color: transparent;
qproperty-drawBase:0;
}
```

This makes the dark grey background as transparent, which bleeds the background from behind it. Or, you can alternatively switch the `background-color` to another color value if you prefer that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Windows

```
QTabWidget::pane{
    border-top: 30px solid #595959;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 40% ); /* For transparent background */
}
```